# Write to localStorage in Scala Play-Framework?

Tags: html, scala, cookies, playframework, local-storage

Is there a way to write to the HTML5 feature: window.localStorage? There is a way to write to a regular cookie, but I was hoping to write to localStorage if the browser can handle it.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't seem to have anything to do with the Play Framework. This sounds like a purely front-end concern. Your Play application won't have any way of directly accessing local storage, other than being sent data from Javascript code via [XHR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest). The advantage of cookies over local storage is that they are sent automatically to the server with the initial browser request, meaning that no XHR or client-side code of any kind is required.

Comment: I actually have the Scala template embedding a script tag to a JavaScript file which is used to write to localStorage. However, I need my scala code to be able to access the info contained in that localStorage. So if I can get scala to read/write to localStorage, then I can have the Scala template pass the info contained in localStorage to the JavaScript. However, if Scala cannot write to localStorage, then I need a way for Scala to communicate to the JavaScript file, which will do reading/writing to localStorage

Comment: The only way to do this is XHR. The only way Scala can know what's going on in local storage on remote machine is if a script on that machine explicitly sends that data back to the server in a separate request. If you're using jQuery, you might use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for example. But without a description of your problem, I can't really give a more specific answer.